# How can I multiply a string.currency field in Freemarker?

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I have the following line of code on a Netsuite PDF/HTML:
${item.rate?string.currency}

I would like to multiply the output of this line by 1.1 to display as GST Inclusive however the only time it works is when i remove the "?string.currency" section. 
When this is removed, I lose the currency formatting.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using brackets? `(1.1 * item.rating)?string.currency`

Comment: Thanks for your help!! That worked! I was adding it to the end rather than the start!

Comment: I explained a bit more in my answer and linked to the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Once you format a number as a currency (by using `?string.currency`), you end up with a string which cannot be manipulated as a number anymore. So, do the manipulation first:

```
${item.rating * 1.1}
```

This will leave you with a number. To format the result as a currency, use brackets around the numeric part of the expression:

```
${(item.rating * 1.1)?string.currency}
```

See also:

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_parentheses